# ¿Cómo sincronizo una barra de navegación en HTML?

Tags: html, css

Hice una barra de navegación haciendo uso de la librería de CSS de W3:

```
<div id="bar" class="w3-bar w3-card w3-2017-ballet-slipper">
            <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                <button id="button" class="w3-button w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Productos</button>
                <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card">
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Producto1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Producto2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Producto3</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button  w3-hover-pink">Blog</a>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                <button id="button" class="w3-button w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Nosotros</button>
                <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card">
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Historia</a>
                    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-2017-ballet-slipper w3-hover-pink">Compromisos Sociales</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Pero quisiera sincronizarla a otras páginas para no tener que cambiar algo en cada página que ponga la barra ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Quieres que haya una barra de navegación, en múltiples páginas ??? Dejala en un archivo "navegacion" e incluyelo en cada página que usa esa barra.

Comment: No se puede hacer eso amigo, necesitaras un freamwork basado en componentes con Angular, React pero react no es un freamwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el `include`  de Php para hacerlo, dejas el código de tu barra de navegación en el mismo directorio y solo lo incluyes en el index y, en vez de `index.html` podrías cambiarle la extensión a `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>My website</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <!-- tu barra de navegación -->
            <?php include "nav.html"; ?>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```